# How to send data from App to server using GcmPubSub

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, gcmlistenerservice

I want my App to send data a "variable" to a server.
I read about 'GcmPubSub', but according to the documentation, the server is the side that can publishs data via a certsin topic while the App should subscripe to that topic. But in my problem it is the other way around, i want my App to publish data to a topic while the server is the side that subscribe to yhe same topic to receive data from the App.

My question is, is it possible to implement such scenario using ' GcmPubSub'? Please advice

Comment: GCM/FCM does not work that way, GCM pushes messages to devices

Comment: @tyczj thanks but can u please tell mehow to send data from the App to the server?which technology is involved

Comment: use a web service

Comment: @tyczj would you please recommend one? I new to such technologies

Comment: @tyczj for such scenario do you think mqtt is useful.

Comment: FCM has [Upstream Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream). Is it not applicable for your use case?